# Convert Acceleration-Time Graph to Velocity Time Graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, calculus

I have a set of 40 readings that make up 2 seconds of simple harmonic motion of an extension spring and I would like to use these readings to come up with a graph and if possible a function that describes the velocity. How would I do this? I would appreciate excel or google sheets explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=a$$ therefore $$v(t) - v(0) =\int_{0}^{t} a(t')\; dt'$$

In terms of what you should do in Excel/Sheets:

To get a particular velocity-time graph, you'd ideally have an initial condition. I.e. you know that $v(0) = 0\;\rm m/s$. I will assume that initially your system is at rest to simplify my calculations.

Consider a table with row indices going from $i=0$ to $i=39$ i.e. 40 rows. I started at 0 because I am use to arrays in computer science, but if it makes you happier, you can start from $i=1$ to $i=40$.

By my convention, $i=0$ represents the first entry in your table -- i.e. the when $t=0\; \rm s$. So, for $i=0$: the time will be $t=0 \; \rm s$, the velocity $v_0$ will be the velocity at $t=0 \; \rm s$ (i.e. $v(0)$), and the acceleration $a_0$ is the acceleration at $t=0.0 \; \rm s$.

Then, for $i=1$: the time will be $t=0.05 \; \rm s$, the velocity $v_1$ will be the velocity at $t=0.05 \; \rm s$ (i.e. $v(0.05)$), and the acceleration $a_1$ is the acceleration at $t=0.05 \; \rm s$. And so on.

I use the following approximation (where $\Delta t = 2\; \rm s/40 \; rows=0.05\; s$):

$$v_{i}=v_{i-1} + a_{i-1}\Delta t$$

which leaves me with the following table:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline i & t & a(t) & v(t) \\ \hline 0 & 0 & a_0 & 0 \\ \hline 1 & 0.05 & a_1 & v_1 = v_0 + a_0 \Delta t \\ \hline 2 & 0.10 & a_2 & v_2 = v_1 + a_1 \Delta t \\ \hline 3 & 0.15 & a_3 & v_3 = v_2 + a_2 \Delta t \\ \hline 4 & 0.20 & a_4 & v_4 = v_3 + a_3 \Delta t \\ \hline 5 & 0.25 & a_5 & v_5 = v_4 + a_4 \Delta t \\ \hline  \end{array}

Another alternative solution is to figure out a polynomial approximation for $a(t)$ (using a computer). Then you can integrate that w.r.t. time.

There are many different numerical methods out there that would help you solve this type of problem -- my solution is quite basic, but with some extra web research, you'll stumble upon some more elegant ones.

EDIT: another good way would be using the trapezoidal rule, namely:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline i & t & a(t) & v(t) \\ \hline 0 & 0 & a_0 & 0 \\ \hline 1 & 0.05 & a_1 & v_1 = \dfrac{a_0 + a_1}{2}\Delta t \\ \hline 2 & 0.10 & a_2 & v_2 = v_1 + \dfrac{a_1 + a_2}{2}\Delta t \\ \hline 3 & 0.15 & a_3 & v_3 = v_2 + \dfrac{a_2 + a_3}{2}\Delta t \\ \hline 4 & 0.20 & a_4 & ... \\ \hline 5 & 0.25 & a_5 & ... \\ \hline  \end{array}